# math.h macro collisions

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, glibc

Macro `DOMAIN` in math.h collides with enums and possibly other types. I don't know what to make of it.

```
#include <algorithm>

enum Type { DOMAIN };


int main(){
    Type t = Type::DOMAIN;
    return 0;

}
```

Compile with flag -std=c++11. The C99 version of this code compiles perfectly fine though:

```
#include <algorithm>

enum Type { DOMAIN };


int main(){
    Type t = DOMAIN;
    return 0;

}
```

I checked the source code and the  library is to blame. algorithm includes stl_algo.h, in which there is ifdef:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <random>     // for std::uniform_int_distribution 
#include <functional> // for std::bind
#endif
```

The following code compiles fine on c++11 compiler:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << DOMAIN << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it a feature or a bug?

## EDIT* dirty fix:

```
#ifdef DOMAIN
#undef DOMAIN
#endif
```

Comment: The `DOMAIN` macro? Where does this come from? I can't find it neither in C++1z nor in C11 drafts..

Comment: Huh. It seems to be related to System V Unix's `matherr` function, not C nor C++. The `__USE_MISC` macro is set (see glibc's `features.h`); otherwise `math.h` wouldn't define the `DOMAIN` macro. It might be possible to get to `_ISOC11_SOURCE` mode to deactivate `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` to get rid of `__USE_MISC`. -- Edit: ... it seems to be more complicated than that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug (or a "wart" if you want to be generous).

All the rest of this answer refers only to GCC and the Gnu standard C library headers. The `man` page references are to a linux system (but I've added links to [man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/)).

The `DOMAIN` macro comes from `math.h`'s System V support. (See [`man matherr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/matherr.3.html).) System V support is normally enabled by defining the `_SVID_SOURCE` feature-test macro (see [`man feature_test_macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)), but it is enabled along with a raft of other extensions if `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined, or by default if no feature test macros are defined.

`gcc` predefines `_GNU_SOURCE` for C programs if the `--std` option is omitted or set to `gnu##`. The various `--std=c##` options cause `__STRICT_ANSI__` to be defined. Consequently, compiling C code with some explicit C standard will suppress the System V extensions. That needs to be done because the System V extensions are not standards-compatible, not even with Posix, because they pollute the global namespace. (`DOMAIN` is just one example of this pollution.)

However, `g++` defines `_GNU_SOURCE` even if `--std=c++##` is specified, and consequently the System V extensions will sneak in. (Thanks to @dyp for the link to this [libstdc++ FAQ entry.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.predefined) and this [long and inconclusive discussion from 2001 on the GCC mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-06/msg00223.html))

An ugly workaround is to set up the features yourself, and then undefine `__USE_SVID`:

```
#include <features.h>
#undef __USE_SVID

#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main(){   
    std::cout << DOMAIN << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

([Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9ffcc3c6cf6cd5f))

IMHO, this should not be necessary. But there it is.

Comment: @dyp: Cool, I'll add that link. Also, my workaround doesn't work (for the reason alluded to in the FAQ entry).

Comment: @dyp, since that thread is from 2001, my tl;dr is "nobody cares enough to fix it."

Comment: ... if this is still the same problem :) but yeah, agreed.

Answer (score -2):

§ 17.6.5.2 [res.on.headers] / 1 of N4140 says:

> A C++ header may include other C++ headers.  A C++ header shall provide the declarations and definitions that appear in its synopsis.  A C++ header shown in its synopsis as including other C++ headers shall provide
>   the declarations and definitions that appear in the synopses of those other headers.

Therefore, it is valid for `<algorithm>` to `#include <cmath>` which injects the offending macro constant into your namespace.

Note, however, that your “quick and dirty fix” is disallowed by the standard (§ 17.6.4.3.1 [macro.names] / 1):

> A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not `#define` or `#undef` names declared in any standard library header.

You'll have to choose a name different from `DOMAIN` for your `enum` constant.

Comment: Well, you quote C++ standard, but this macro is platform-specific. Hence, C++ requirements do not apply here.

Comment: The standard doesn't permit `cmath` to define `DOMAIN`, so I don't see why it should be a problem to undefine it. :) But note that `DOMAIN` is not the only macro defined.

Comment: @rici _The standard doesn't permit cmath to define DOMAIN_ - not quite right. The C++ standard doesn't specify or require macro `DOMAIN` to be defined. However, the OS must follow other standards in addition to C++, such as POSIX. E.g. POSIX requires `void*` to be compatible with function and data pointers, C++ does not require that.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Section 1.4, para. 8 "A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), *provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program*." 2.10 para 3 outlines the identifier names reserved for use by the implementation; `DOMAIN` is not such a name, so it cannot be a standard library extension. It could be defined in a non-standard library header (such as a Posix header), but it cannot be defined by a standard library header such as `<random>`. Posix conforms to this restriction; there is no conflict.